# At a radio ip address (interface login) , I want the browser to auto fill the user and password and login, repeat until login is sucessful

Tags: python, html, css, batch-processing

I have hundreds of radio equipment and cameras to log into to change settings , firmware , etc.
I repetitively retype the same 6 or 8 different usernames and passwords until I find the correct ones that work with that device, sometimes I type 60 - 100 times a day!

What I would like:
When I type the devices ip address into a browser, some program (insert mystery code here) goes to a user/password txt file grabs first username and password, fills in fields and enter. If login fails, it goes to the next set, etc. It only stops when login is successful.

I need some ideas or advice on what directions to head to create this.

Thanks

I tried using password savers but there are a lot of common ip addresses on the hundreds of lans with different passwords. do I need to build something? is there something at already exists?

thanks
max